# QEvent::Close not triggered from changeEvent

Tags: c++, qt4

Hello: I'm running a clock in a background and I'd like to disable the close event and inform the user that first stop the clock. I already know about the reimplementation of closeEvent, **but** I would like to try it in changeEvent reimplementation. This is the code about it:

```
void AlarmUI::changeEvent (QEvent *event) {
    switch (event->type()) {
        case QEvent::WindowStateChange: {
            if (isMinimized()) hide();
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::Close: {
            if (m_timer->isActive()) event->ignore ();
                event->accept();
            break;
        }
        default: {
            QMainWindow::changeEvent (event);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The above doesn't stop the close event while the clock is active...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#changeEvent) says, change events do not include `QEvent::Close`.

You should reimplement `QWidget::closeEvent` anyway.

Comment: @Joel `QEvent::type()` describes all available events, including `QEvent::Close`. `QWidget::changeEvent` handles events of certain types, which do not include `QEvent::Close`.